# How do we call the self.n under the __iter__(self)? Is it a instance attribute?

Tags: python-3.x

I guess self.n is not an instance attribute because it does not appear under the constructor section. How do you call it?

```
class PowTwo:
    """Class to implement an iterator
    of powers of two"""

    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n <= self.max:
            result = 2 ** self.n
            self.n += 1
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Comment: It is still an instance attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As a commenter says, it's still an instance attribute.

Python classes are completely dynamic, which means that you can go ahead and define new instance attributes whenever you want, e.g. `self.n = 0` in this example. As a matter of good programming style, usually they are defined in `__init__`, but that is only a convention.

IMO, in your code example, it would be better style to define `self.n` in `__init__` -- that way you can't have an inconsistent class instance that doesn't have `self.n` defined. I.e.:

```py
    def __init__(self, max = 0):
        self.n = None
        self.max = max

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self
```

Additionally, it would probably be better to document that `self.n` is used privately, by renaming it to `self._n`.

Comment: I'd probably add that the `self.n` should be named `self._n` to document that this attribute is used as a private attribute.